# Subtraction of dates in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Today working with dates in Oracle, perform a subtraction of date with the following query:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS HOY, 
      TO_DATE(T.FECHA, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS FECHA, 
      TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') - TO_DATE(T.FECHA, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS RESTA 
FROM table t
WHERE T.FECHA IS NOT NULL
```

Which I throw the following results:

[image]

As you can see the subtraction gives me negative results, of course they are not expected, making tests made the following query:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS HOY, 
       TO_DATE(T.FECHA, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS FECHA, 
       TO_DATE(SYSDATE) - TO_DATE(T.FECHA, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS RESTA 
FROM table t
WHERE T.FECHA IS NOT NULL
```

Which I throw the following results:

[image]

These are the expected results. Here my question is what is the difference between doing the subtraction of the following way `TO_DATE (SYSDATE, 'DD / MM / YYYY') - TO_DATE (T.FECHA, 'DD / MM / YYYY')` to the way that I I throw the correct results `TO_DATE (SYSDATE) - TO_DATE (T.FECHA, 'DD / MM / YYYY')`?

As you notice the field `T.FECHA` is`VARCHAR2`.

Comment: Both are wrong. `SYSDATE` is already a date and doing a `TO_DATE()` on it leads to incorrect results

Comment: Additional info to Kaushik Nayak anwser - SYSDATE contains time component in Oracle. I would recommend you to do trunc(sysdate, 'DD'), when you would like to get only date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be part of a rather large group of users who choose to store date values into `VARCHAR2` columns; as usual, that's a bad idea - change it, if possible.

Here's an example which show what you should have done:

```
SQL> create table hp_transact_res_Eval_hipo (fechaeval varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into hp_transact_res_Eval_hipo
  2    select '13/05/2009' from dual union
  3    select '14/05/2009' from dual union
  4    select '08/05/2009' from dual union
  5    select '23/07/2010' from dual union
  6    select '22/09/2010' from dual;

5 rows created.
```

- apply `TO_CHAR` to `SYSDATE` (which is a function that returns the `DATE` datatype value) with appropriate format mask to display it as dd/mm/yyyy
- select `FECHAEVAL` as it is, as you've already stored it as dd/mm/yyyy, so - no use in converting it to date (with `TO_DATE`)
- as subtracting two date values produces number of days between those two values, I applied the `TRUNC` function to `SYSDATE` in order to remove time component from it, and `TO_DATE` to `FECHAEVAL` to convert it to date.

---

```
SQL> select
  2    to_char(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') as hoy,
  3    fechaeval as fecha,
  4    trunc(sysdate) - to_date(fechaeval, 'dd/mm/yyyy') as resta
  5  from hp_transact_res_Eval_hipo;

HOY        FECHA                     RESTA
---------- -------------------- ----------
28/04/2018 08/05/2009                 3277
28/04/2018 13/05/2009                 3272
28/04/2018 14/05/2009                 3271
28/04/2018 22/09/2010                 2775
28/04/2018 23/07/2010                 2836

SQL>
```

Finally, to show you why you shouldn't store date values into `VARCHAR2` columns: this is a valid *string* (and can be inserted into the table), but invalid *date*. Subtraction - as expected - results in an error:

```
SQL> insert into hp_transact_res_eval_hipo values ('33/44/5555');

1 row created.

SQL> select trunc(sysdate) - to_date(fechaeval, 'dd/mm/yyyy') as resta
  2  from hp_transact_res_eval_hipo;
ERROR:
ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month



no rows selected

SQL>
```

You'll have *huge* problems if someone enters a value similar to mine. Once again: switch to `DATE` datatype column.